# How to use indexing by matching strings in data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, mapping

I try to resolve the following problem. I have two data sets, say df1 and df2:

```
df1

NameSP  Val       Char1 BVA
0   'ACCR'  0.091941     A  Y'
1   'SDRE'  0.001395     S  Y'
2   'ACUZ'  0.121183     A  N'
3   'SRRE'  0.001512     S  N'
4   'FFTR'  0.035609     F  N'
5   'STZE'  0.000637     S  N'
6   'AHZR'  0.001418     A  Y'
7   'DEES'  0.000876     D  N'
8   'UURR'  0.023878     U  Y'
9   'LLOH'  0.004371     L  Y'
10  'IUUT'  0.049102     I  N'


df2

NameSP   Val1   Glob
0  'ACCR'  0.234  20000
1  'FFTR'  0.222  10000
2  'STZE'  0.001   5000
3  'DEES'  0.006   2000
4  'UURR'  0.134  20000
5  'LLOH'  0.034  10000
```

I would like to perform indexing of df2 in df1, and then use the indexing vector for various matrix operation. This would be something similar to strmatch(A,B,'exact') in Matlab. I can get the indexing properly by using .iloc and then .isin as in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('C:\PYTHONCODES\LINEAROPT\TEST_DATA1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('C:\PYTHONCODES\LINEAROPT\TEST_DATA2.xlsx')

print(df1)
print(df2)

ddf1 = df1.iloc[:,0]
ddf2 = df2.iloc[:,0]

pindex = ddf1[ddf1.isin(ddf2)]

print(pindex.index)
```

which gives me:

```
Int64Index([0, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

But I can not find the way to use this index for mapping and building my arrays. As an example, I would like to have a vector that has the same number of elements that df1, but with Val1 values from df2 at indexed positions and zeros everywhere else. So it should look like that:

```
0.234
0
0
0
0.222
0.001
0
0.006
0.134
0.034
0
```

Or another mapping problem. How to use such indexing to map the values from colon "Val" in df1 in a vector that would contain Val from df1 at indexed rows and zeros everywhere else. So this time it should look like:

```
0.091941
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.035609
0.000637
0.0
0.000876
0.023878
0.004371
0.0
```

Any idea of how to that in efficient and elegant way?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem**

```
df2.set_index('NameSP')['Val1'].reindex(df1['NameSP']).fillna(0)
```

**Second problem**

```
df1['Val1'].where(df1['NameSP'].isin(df2['NameSP']), 0)
```

Comment: Fantastic! This works great for the first problem. Thanks. For the second one it's perfect too. Thanks so much!

Comment: len of df1 or df2 for second problem?